# Convert at::Tensor to double in C++ when using LibTorch (PyTorch)

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

In the following code, I want to compare the `loss` (data type `at::Tensor`) with a `lossThreshold` (data type `double`). I want to convert `loss` to `double` before making that comparison. How do I do it?

```cpp
int main() {
    auto const input1(torch::randn({28*28});
    auto const input2(torch::randn({28*28});
    double const lossThreshold{0.05};
    auto const loss{torch::nn::functional::mse_loss(input1, input2)}; // this returns an at::Tensor datatype
    return loss > lossThreshold ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to GitHub CoPilot which recommended this solution. I guess I should leave my job now. :(

The solution is using the `item<T>()` template function as follows:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto const input1(torch::randn({28*28}); // at::Tensor
    auto const input2(torch::randn({28*28}); // at::Tensor
    double const lossThreshold{0.05}; // double
    auto const loss{torch::nn::functional::mse_loss(input1, input2).item<double>()}; // the item<double>() converts at::Tensor to double
    return loss > lossThreshold ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```